# Missing definitions MVC Views Visual Studio Intellisense

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, web-config, intellisense, definitions

I have a Github project which is an ASP.NET MVC website. There's no trouble in pulling and running the project now. However when coding I get all sorts of errors with e.g:

```
@ViewBag
@Html.LabelFor
@Scripts
```

Errors:

> The name 'Scrips/ViewBag' does not exist in the current context
>
> 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition
>   for 'LabelFor' and no extension method 'Label'For' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've tried updating Owin in the Nuget console using:

```
Update-Package owin -reinstall
```

which made it able to run the project

`web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="HackMySite" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My partners who also work on this project are also working in Visual Studio and they seem to have no trouble with this.

Which is exactly the same with another project I would make myself.

Comment: I solved it by updating my Visual Studio to 2013 update 4

Answer (score 0):

So after searching for missing packages I noticed I still had updates. After updating my Visual Studio it all worked like a charm.

I'm guessing it has something to do with Visual Studio 2013 update 4